PostgreSQL: SELECT * INTO new_table FROM table in DO block
I want to create a new table from an existing table in a DO block, but I get an error telling me that new_table is an unknown variable. The DO block is used because I do lots of other things in it where I need some variables too.
Here a simplified example:
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        v_id INT;
    BEGIN
        v_id := 1;

        SELECT * INTO new_table FROM table WHERE id = v_id;
    END
$$


FROM table ... TABLE is a reserved keyword in Postgres.  Did you really name your table as table ?

select into has a different meaning in pl/pgsql - store a query result into a variable. Use SQL-standard create table as instead. create table new_table as select * from "table" where id = v_id;

@Stefanov.sm Thanks for your hint - can you please post your comment as answer!

select into has a different meaning in PL/pgSQL - store a query result into a variable. Please see the documentation.
Use SQL-standard create table as instead. Here is the simplified example with the change. Parentheses around the select subquery are optional.
DO
$$
  DECLARE
    v_id INT;
  BEGIN
    v_id := 1;
    create table new_table as (select * from "table" where id = v_id);
  END;
$$;

